# Same-parity in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I am trying to solve the exercise 2.20 from SICP book. The exercise -

```
Write a procedure same-parity that takes one or more integers and returns a list of
all the arguments that have the same even-odd parity as the first argument. For example,
(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
    (1 3 5 7)
(same-parity 2 3 4 5 6 7)
    (2 4 6)
```

My code -

```
(define same-parity (lambda (int . l)
    (define iter-even (lambda (l2 rl)
        (cons ((null? l2) rl)
              ((even? (car l2))
                  (iter-even (cdr l2) (append rl (car l2))))
          (else (iter-even (cdr l2) rl)))))

    (define iter-odd (lambda (l2 rl)
        (cons ((null? l2) rl)
              ((odd? (car l2))
                  (iter-odd (cdr l2) (append rl (car l2))))
          (else (iter-odd (cdr l2) rl)))))

    (if (even? int) (iter-even l (list int))
        (iter-odd l (list int)))))
```

For some reason I am getting an error saying "The object (), passed as the first argument to cdr, is not the correct type". I tried to solve this for more than two hours, but I cant find any reason why it fails like that. Thanks for hlep.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(define same-parity 
  (lambda (int . l)
    (define iter-even 
      (lambda (l2 rl)
        (cond ((null? l2) rl)
              ((even? (car l2))
               (iter-even (cdr l2) (append rl (list (car l2)))))
              (else (iter-even (cdr l2) rl)))))    
    (define iter-odd 
      (lambda (l2 rl)
        (cond ((null? l2) rl)
              ((odd? (car l2))
               (iter-odd (cdr l2) (append rl (list (car l2)))))
              (else (iter-odd (cdr l2) rl)))))
    (if (even? int)
        (iter-even l (list int))
        (iter-odd  l (list int)))))
```

Explanation:

- You are using `cons` instead of `cond` for the different conditions
- in the part where `append` is called, the second argument must be a proper list (meaning: null-terminated) - but it is a `cons`-pair in your code. This was causing the error, the solution is to simply put the second element inside a list before appending it.

I must say, using `append` to build an output list is frowned upon. You should try to write the recursion in such a way that `cons` is used for creating the new list, this is more efficient, too.

Some final words - as you're about to discover in the next section of SICP, this problem is a perfect fit for using [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) - a more idiomatic solution would be:

```
(define (same-parity head . tail)
  (if (even? head)
      (filter even? (cons head tail))
      (filter  odd? (cons head tail))))
```

Comment: I know quite little about lisp, but is it really good to have two almost identical functions? wouldn't it be more efficient to get the first item of the input list, then build an output with those items which give an even difference (or sum) with that copied first item (which, of course, includes the first item itself)?

Comment: @CiaPan yes, that's why my proposed solution uses only one helper: `filter`. It's enough to pass the thing that changes (the predicate) so we don't duplicate code

Answer (score 0):

While you are traversing the list, you might as well just split it into even and odd parities.  As the last step, choose the one you want.

```
(define (parities args)
  (let looking ((args args) (even '()) (odd '()))
    (if (null? args)
        (values even odd)
        (let ((head (car args)))
          (if (even? head)
              (looking (cdr args) (cons head even) odd)
              (looking (cdr args) even (cons head odd)))))))

(define (same-parity head . rest)
  (let-values ((even odd) (parities (cons head rest)))
    (if (even? head)
        even
        odd)))
```

Except for homework assignments, if you are going to look for one then you are likely to need the other.  Said another way, you'd find yourself using `parities` more frequently in practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, I check the first element in the list. If it is even, I call the procedure that forms a list out of only the even elements. Else, I call the procedure that forms a list out of odd elements.

Here's my code

```
(define (parity-helper-even B)(cond
                           ((= 1 (length B)) (cond
                                              ((even? (car B)) B)
                                              (else '())

                                              ))
                           (else (cond
                                   ((even? (car B)) (append (list (car B)) (parity-helper-even (cdr B))))
                                   (else (parity-helper-even(cdr B)))


                               ))))




(define (parity-helper-odd B)(cond
                           ((= 1 (length B)) (cond
                                              ((odd? (car B)) B)
                                              (else '())

                                              ))
                           (else (cond
                                   ((odd? (car B)) (append (list (car B)) (parity-helper-odd (cdr B))))
                                   (else (parity-helper-odd (cdr B)))


                               ))))



(define (same-parity first . L) (cond
                                  ((even? first) (parity-helper-even (append (list first) L)))
                                  (else (parity-helper-odd (append (list first) L)))))



(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
;Output (1 3 5 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply filter elements by parity of first element:

```
(define (same-parity x . y)
  (define (iter z filter-by)
    (cond ((null? z) z)
          ((filter-by (car z))
           (cons (car z) (iter (cdr z) filter-by)))
          (else (iter (cdr z) filter-by))))
  (iter (cons x y) (if (even? x) even? odd?)))
```

And try:

```
(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
(same-parity 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```